# Defining font-size of custom font in CSS for the entire project

Tags: css

What's the standard way to selectively define the font-size of one of the fonts among a gamut of font-families in CSS?

For instance, I'm trying to have `my_font` appear at `25px` size via the following short-hand:

```
body{

font-family:helvetica,'my_font',arial,sans-serif;

font:helvetica,25px 'my_font',arial,sans-serif;

}
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work.

Comment: use `font-size:20px;` or if you prefer `em` use `font-size:1.4em;`

Comment: @Jorden1337: only looking to change `my_font`'s font size, not of any other font in the families declared.

Comment: Depending on your html you can select different content areas and give them a unique font style. For example if you have a header, .main-content, and footer, you can style the body fonts there as you wish in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is no. The idea of a [font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) is that it's a family of fonts not a single version or size.

Probably the best you can do is to just add `font-size` to each class or css selection that uses that font.

Comment: That's quite a bummer. The font's pretty ubiquitous and it's a large-ish project.

Comment: I hate to give you a bummer answer, buthere we are. Maybe you could do a find and replace to quickly add all the font sizes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should declare a class where you specify your font and your font-size and then use it specifically where you want. For example:

```
<div class="myclass">

.myclass {
font-family: 'myFont',
font-size: your-size
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That would be the `@font-face` property. It's a property where you can define multiple font families and even modify a specific type of font to your preferences. It goes something like this

```css
body {
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'my-font';
    src: url(path-to-font);
    font-size: 24px;
 }
}
```

Read more about it here: http://www.font-face.com/#green_content

Comment: `font-face` was the first place I tried setting the font-size for `my_font`. It hasn't worked for me. It doesn't seem `font-face` accepts the `font-size` attr

Comment: `font-size` is not a attribute that can be used with `@font-face` as of right now

Comment: Yeah, I see it turns red. My bad then. I thought that that should help. I guess I gave the wrong answer.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `font` property from the `body`, and leave the `font-family` with multiple fonts and then just add the `font-size` in the next line?